# SignalR strongly typed hub use InvokeAsync instead of SendAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

When using a strongly typed hub a method call that doesn't return anything seems to be calling `SendAsync` and not waiting for a return because exceptions are not coming back. When a method has a return value and an exception occurs, the exception is sent back.

Is there a way to have methods without a return value use `InvokeAsync` or some other way to have an exception sent back when there isn't a return value?

Worst case I could have it always return a dummy value.

Comment: Is it a hub exception you want to send back to client? How about try catch the error in hub then sendAsync it back to client ?

Comment: That's not how strongly typed hubs work. You only have the methods you create in the client interface.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-results

Comment: @Brennan I'm not sending results back but I want exceptions to come back.

Comment: Well that's not possible unless you use client results.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, Yes. I used InvokeAsync instead of SendAsync it returns the specific error information. 
This is a server hub method without return values. But there is a exception.

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub<IChatClient>
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();

            //await Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(user, message);

        }
    }
```

In the client side Use `InvokeAsync` instead of `SendAsync`

```
    private async Task Send()
    {
        if (hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", userInput, messageInput);
        }
    }
```

The client side console receives error:
[image]
There is no error appears if use `SendAsync`

Comment: The client is the one that throws the exception. You have it in reverse.

Comment: @JoshClose Sorry for misunderstanding. The hub reveive error from one of the client right? How about add a method in client interface? So you can try catch the error and send it back to client.